# Disable output buffering in tomcat 6 for comet servlet

Tags: servlets, buffer, tomcat6, comet

I use comet with tomcat 6 to push data to the clients.

I want to receive data before connection closes (ready state = 3 for the XMLHttpRequest), and the problem is that tomcat 6 buffers data before sending it, so that i need to make tricky things to achieve doing this.

I have set request content type to application/x-javascript and req content type to application/xml (in order to disable browser cache).

I have used many available options in tomcat 6 to disable cache (socketBuffer = -1 in nio connector, etc....), and this works in my local tomcat 6 (on windows os) (actually, even without modifying any default option).

But, event with the same configuration of tomcat 6, when i deploy the application on a tomcat 6 server provided by http://jelastic.com , the server output buffer is big and i am obliged to send empty bytes to trigger output writer flushing (cf. following code)

byte[] bytes = new byte[event.getHttpServletResponse().getBufferSize()-new Gson().toJson(messagesContent).getBytes().length];
  event.getHttpServletResponse().getOutputStream().write(new Gson().toJson(messagesContent).getBytes());
event.getHttpServletResponse().getOutputStream().write(bytes);
event.getHttpServletResponse().getOutputStream().flush();

If i dont write the bytes in addition to my data content, the data is not sent to the client. This is really annoying, cause i send useless empty bytes, and because i have to manage these empty bytes on the client. Horrible.

Does anyone have a solution ? How to disable comet servlet output buffer. It seems so obvious to me that the output buffer should be disabled for a comet servlet by default. Sounds weird.

Thanks by advance,

J

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using Filters?
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html in Programming Customized Requests and Responses

Using the decorator pattern you can control the output.
The way to do this is to pass the servlet that generates the response a stand-in stream. The stand-in stream prevents the servlet from closing the original response stream when it completes.

```
class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private CharArrayWriter output;
    public String toString() {
      return output.toString();
    }
    public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response); 
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
    }
    public PrintWriter getWriter(){
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }

}
```

So in the doFilter method of the filter you get the original PrintWritter, pass the wrapper

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
CharResponseWrapper wrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);
chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
```

And then The Servlet will writte all the output in the CharrArrayWritter so you can get the output in a string without buffering

```
wrapper.toString()
```

then you can modify, append.. etc, and then use the original response output to writte the content.

```
out.write(wrapper.toString());
out.close();
```